# Not being able to display comments in template

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Post and Comment model by taking reference from internet. i created and Post and Comment model and it looks ok in django admin panel. i can add post and also a comment to any particular post. but getting trouble when I'm trying to display the comment under the post in templates(under post detail views). PLEASE HELP

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,max_length=50,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('discuss')
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    return get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post= post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail',pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'discuss/comment_form.html',{'form':form})

def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post-detail', pk=post_pk)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="medaia-body">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="image not found">
    <div class="article-metedata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{object.author}}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"}}</small>
    </div>
    <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
    <img class="query-img" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="image not found">
    <p class="article-content">{{ object.content|safe }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% if object.author == user %}
<div class="post-update-delete">
  <a href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit Post</button></a>
  <a href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete Post</button></a>
</div>
{% endif %}
<hr>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-comment" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
<!-- ############################### ABOVE CODE IS WORKING ############################# -->
<!-- ########################## GETTING PROBLEM IN BELLOW CODE ######################### --> 
  {% for comment in object.comments.all %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      {{ comment.create_date }}
      {{ comment.text|safe|linebreaks }}
      {{ comment.author }}
  {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
  <p>No Comment</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

in post_deatil.html i also tried  {% for comment in post.comments.all %} but it is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify a [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), the `related_name` is by default `comment_set`, so you iterate over the comments with:

```
{% for comment in object.comment_set.all %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: hey Willem, thank you so much that template thing worked. but i think i'm still doing something wrong in my views.py because when i'm going to the URL for adding comment from my app (not from admin panel) it gives me error  ** AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'get' **

Comment: @SurajPrakash: can you edit the question and share the *full* traceback?

Comment: i will but first let me try everything. if nothing will work i will edit the post. and thank you so much again.